# How to increment excel references using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, excel

create a function that will increment the excel sheet reference using JavaScript.

I have the string values that contains the excel sheet formulas and i need to increment these reference using JavaScript. Here is an example of what i am trying to achieve

**Example 1**

```
const str1 = "$A$1+1"
```

and the result will be

```
["$A$1+1", "$A$2+1", "$A$3+1", "$A$3+1"]
```

**example 2**

```
const str2 = "$A$10+$B$9"
```

result

```
 ["$A$10+$B$9", "$A$11+$B$10", "$A$12+$B$11", "$A$13+$B$12"]
```

I tried using `split` method but it didn't help me to at all

```
 for(i=0; i<4; i++){
   
   let arr = str1.split('$')
   ...

}
```

Comment: Where's your code attempt?

Comment: @LeeTaylor I had added my code attempt in the question. but it seems that I was not going in the right direction